# What instead global functions in OOP?

Tags: php, oop

Many people claim that global functions used in OOP are bad idea because you cannot test (mock) them. What should I use instead? Always dependency injection?
I have some **toolbox** with many small functions that do particular and useful things. E.g. convert strings, do some calculations, clean messy HTML, etc. It's very handy to use them in the code. For example:

```
public function copyUploadedFile($filename, $dst_dir)
{
    $filename = convertToSimpleString($filename);
    if (!$filename) $error = displayError('Filename is empty!');
    $extension = getFileExtension($filename);
    $dst_dir = convertToSimpleString($dst_dir);
    if (!isDir($dst_dir)) createDir($dst_dir);
    ....
}
```

Dependency injection makes the code more complicated and always force to create new object even for very small job:

```
$file = new FileManager(new ErrorHandler, new StringConverter, new DirManager ...)

public function __construct(ErrorHandler $error_handler, StringConverter $string_converter, DirManager $dir_manager, ...)
{
    $this->error_handler = $error_handler;
    $this->string_converter = $string_converter;
    $this->dir_manager = $div_manager;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do you write unit tests?

Comment: I have to rewrite the code and I plan to do unit tests.

Comment: According to problems with unit tests - there is a library AspectMock (https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock) which allows you to stub and mock static and global functions: https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock

Answer (score 1):

Dependency injection is the pattern of **Inversion of Control**. The control of the dependencies is inverted from one being called to the one calling.

The main advantage: the one at the top of the caller chain is always you. You can control all dependencies and have complete control over how your application works. You can replace a dependency by another (one you made for example).

For example what if Library X uses Logger Y and you want to make it use your logger Z? With dependency injection, you don't have to change the code of Library X.

http://php-di.org/doc/understanding-di.html

Every pattern that is applied incorrectly becomes an anti-pattern. Dependency injection is used to inject "Injectables" (e.g. Services, Repositories, Database, Template engine, Logger) from outside into the "core" of the application. DI is not intended to be used for "[Newables](https://qafoo.com/blog/111_injectables_newables.html)" Examples for Newables are Value Objects, DTO's and POCO's. This kind of objects can (should) be created without DI.

PHP supports a mix of OOP and procedural style. The global functions like `file_get_contents` can be used everywhere. BUT the problem (or question) is: How to you want to **unit test** that? 1. solution: Use [vfsStream](http://vfs.bovigo.org/) as a virtual file system to mock the real file system. 2. solution: Use a OOP Interface ([1](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php), [2](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html)) and inject the mock objects.

I think one of the main benefits of DI are:

- The (injectable) classes are no longer tightly coupled to its dependency
- Simplification of unit tests
- There are more reasons of course

To manage the new complexity I would recommend a tool like [PHP-DI](http://php-di.org/). Caching should be enabled on the prod server to improve performance. Everything has its price; -)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to distinguish between two types of functions: PHP's native function and user-defined functions.

When you use PHP's built-in functions within any of your classes, the only ones, that will affect the testability (and behavior in general), will be function which access some external global state. For example function like `time()` and `php_sapi_name()` depend on a global state, that exists outside your application. The best practice would be to pass them in as a parameter in an object's method or in the constructor (dependency injection).

> <sub>**NOTE**: if that is not possible, then alternative is to wrap when in a class method and use reflection to alter their behavior, when running unit tests.</sub>

As for function like `array_key_exists()` or `strpost()`, those actually manipulate the existing application state and will always have a predictable result. They will not have any detrimental effect on the testability of your code.

BUT, you were not actually talking about those.

When it comes to user-defined functions, those are not actually testable. Which means that you either have to treat them as "trusted" (which is a questionable idea), or you have to avoid them.

I would recommend avoiding them, if you intention is to actually use object-oriented paradigm, since they are core concept of procedural paradigm and will actually cause your OOP code to become a mess.

Also, watch this lecture: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHBrDWIKW8Q

---

Now, the practical part.

It all starts from the top level API, that you use. As I see it, at the high level your code should look kinda like this:

```
try {
    $file = new File($filename);   
    $storage->move($file, '/path/to/destination');
} catch (EmptyFilename $exception) {
    echo 'File name is missing!';
} catch (DirectoryNotWritable $exception) {
    echo 'Yeah no, you cant write there. Get lost!';
}
```

The "is this file actually valid upload" part should be a responsibility of the file's abstraction. Same goes for code like `$file->getExtension()`, while the "moving file" should be a responsibility of your storage abstraction.

And your storage abstraction should not be responsible for formatting the proper error message. Instead it should just throw an exception and let something higher in the call-stack to deal with the rendering.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The code above was just an example showing problem of use of global functions. Yes, you are right, of course it should be devided into separate classes. But, as I understand, **dependency injection** is the only right solution in this case?
What are "EmptyFilename" and "DirectoryNotWritable" in your piece of code? Classes extending Exception?

Comment: Yes, those are exceptions. I personally find it a bad style to add suffix for exceptions and interfaces.